# Can Firefox Inspector change files on server?

Tags: php, firefox

I'm playing around with
Firefox Inspector and change some things
on a web page. 
Now the web hoster writes to tell me that the webpage will be hacked.
I watch the page via www, don't have any passwords or so.
Is this coincidence or can I really make changes on the server
with the inspector?

The hoster write the affected file was  `/cache_ac67f2ce3f.php`.

Comment: Hi @chris919, welcome to SO or sort of ... What SO should not be : - a place where questions are badly asked. Please indulge on how to ask a good question -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . All the best

Comment: So funny :) , i think your web hoster want to kidding with you :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change files on the server using the inspector.